# Cannot use as type in assignment in go

Tags: go

when I compile my code, I get the following error message, not sure why it happens.  Can someone help me point why?  Thank you in advance.

> cannot use px.InitializePaxosInstance(val) (type PaxosInstance) as
> type *PaxosInstance in assignment

```
type Paxos struct {
    instance   map[int]*PaxosInstance
}    

type PaxosInstance struct {
    value        interface{}
    decided      bool
}    

func (px *Paxos) InitializePaxosInstance(val interface{}) PaxosInstance {
    return PaxosInstance {decided:false, value: val}
}

func (px *Paxos) PartAProcess(seq int, val interface{}) error {  
    px.instance[seq] = px.InitializePaxosInstance(val)
    return nil 
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your map is expecting a pointer to a `PaxosInstance` (`*PaxosInstance`), but you are passing a struct value to it. Change your Initialize function to return a pointer.

```
func (px *Paxos) InitializePaxosInstance(val interface{}) *PaxosInstance {
    return &PaxosInstance {decided:false, value: val}
}
```

Now it returns a pointer. You can take the pointer of a variable using `&` and, should you need the struct value itself, dereference it again with `*`.

After a line like

```
x := &PaxosInstance{}
```

or

```
p := PaxosInstance{}
x := &p
```

the value type of `x` is `*PaxosInstance`. And if you ever need to, you can dereference it back into a `PaxosInstance` struct value with

```
p = *x
```

You usually do not want to pass structs around as actual values, because Go is pass-by-value, which means it will copy the whole thing. Using struct values with maps and slices often results in logic errors because a copy is made should you iterate them or otherwise reference them except via index. It depends on your use-case, but your identifier `Instance` would infer that you would want to avoid duplications and such logic errors.

As for reading the compiler errors, you can see what it was telling you. The type `PaxosInstance` and type `*PaxosInstance` are not the same.

Comment: After I change that, I get new error message                                             "cannot use PaxosInstance literal (type *PaxosInstance) as type PaxosInstance in return argument"

Comment: There are two changes in my answer. `*PaxosInstance` on the first line, and the `&` on the return line. Did you make both changes?

Answer (score 6):

The `instance` field within the `Paxos` struct is a map of integer keys to *pointers*  to `PaxosInstance` structs.

When you call:

```
px.instance[seq] = px.InitializePaxosInstance(val)
```

You're attempting to assign a concrete (not pointer) `PaxosInstance` struct into an element of `px.instance`, which are pointers.

You can alleviate this by returning a pointer to a `PaxosInstance` in `InitializePaxosInstance`, like so:

```
func (px *Paxos) InitializePaxosInstance(val interface{}) *PaxosInstance {
    return &PaxosInstance{decided: false, value: val}
}
```

or you could modify the `instance` field within the `Paxos` struct to not be a map of pointers:

```
type Paxos struct {
    instance   map[int]PaxosInstance
}
```

Which option you choose is up to your use case.

Comment: Generally it isn't a good idea to store a map of struct values. Each time you set or get it, a copy is made. Struct pointers almost always win out in go

Comment: I think "generally" and "up to your use case" are fairly similar phrases. :)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else pulling their hair out: check your imports.

Not sure when it started happening, but my Visual Studio Code + gopls setup will occasionally insert an import line that references my vendored dependencies path instead of the original import path. I usually won't catch this until I start polishing code for release, or an error like this one pops up.

In my case this caused two otherwise identical types to not compare equally. Once I fixed my imports this resolved the error.