# Go - Cannot use as type in assignment

Tags: go

I'm new in Go Lang.

I confused why this error message still coming.

> cannot use cmd.Args() (type cli.Args) as type CmdArgs in assignment

The error message explain that `cmd.Args() (type cli.Args)` cannot assignment to `type CmdArgs` which is `type CmdArgs` is `cli.Args`.

I have read [Cannot use as type in assignment in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43900806/cannot-use-as-type-in-assignment-in-go), but it does not make me understand where's my wrong is. I think that's a different matter with me.

Any solution please?

Here's my code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/urfave/cli"
)

// CmdArgs is command arguments
type CmdArgs cli.Args

func main() {
    program := cli.NewApp()
    program.Action = func(cmd *cli.Context) error {
        var args CmdArgs
        args = cmd.Args()
               ▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼
               cannot use cmd.Args() (type cli.Args) as type CmdArgs in assignment

        return nil
    }

    program.Run(os.Args)
}
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: your declaration of `CmdArgs` creates a new type. Why are you creating a new type?

Comment: I don't know what this kind you called. 
`func (ca CmdArgs) Len() int {
 return len(ca)
}`
I have plan to use that.

Comment: What is your plan to use that? The only reason to declare a new type is to replace the method set from the underlying type, but there is rarely any reason to do this. You can make a type that can be converted with the same underlying type, which would be less confusing, but again one normally would just use `cli.Args` if you're interoperating with that particular `cli` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means exactly what it says: you're trying to assign the return value of a function to a variable that's of a different type than the return value, which is invalid. When you define a new type, it's a new type, and not directly assignable. You can *cast* between them, but there is *no implicit casting in Go* - the cast *must* be done explicitly:

```
    var args CmdArgs
    normalArgs := cmd.Args()
    args = CmdArgs(normalArgs)
```

Though I have to wonder why you're creating a new type `CmdArgs` to begin with, but I assume there's some reason that's not indicated in the code example. You might have an easier time embedding rather than aliasing, however.

Answer (score 1):

`args` is a variable of type `CmdArgs` which has a vairable of type `cli.Args`

Change your function to

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/urfave/cli"
)

func main() {
    program := cli.NewApp()
    program.Action = func(cmd *cli.Context) error {
        args := cmd.Args()
        return nil
    }

    program.Run(os.Args)
}
```

and it should run.